# How to Install a toolset in Fiji or ImageJ

Tags: imagej, fiji, imagej-macro

New to FIJI and ImageJ here, so I apologize if this question sounds idiotic to the veterans. I came across a really cool toolset that can deblur laser scanning microscopy images here: http://image.bio.methods.free.fr/lsmtrans.html but it is missing from my newly downloaded FIJI release. I think I found the code here: http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/macros/toolsets/LSM%20Transmission%20Deblurring.txt but I have no idea how to install it by hand. Do I need to save it notepad++ as a .jar (code looks like java) or .ijm file? Or is there a way to search for it from the FIJI application?

My FIJI version: ImageJ 1.52p Java 1.8.0_172 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

To manually install a Toolset:

- Save a local copy of the file (txt extension)
- Navigate to `Macros/Toolsets` inside your Fiji installation (on a Mac, access this by right clicking on the Fiji app in a Finder window and selecting "Show Package Contents")
- Copy the file to this location
- Restart Fiji if it was running
- Toolset is available by clicking `>>` in the toolbar